# How can I convert a iSCSI system disk from XenServer to another format

Tags: xen, migration, iscsi, xenserver, proxmox

Perhaps this is quite a silly question. I installed a new VM on XenServer. It loads the full system from a iSCSI from a NAS. Now I am planning to migrate to Proxmox as XenServer falls short regarding USB passthrough. Nevertheless, I don't have a clue on how to:

a) Access the iSCSI disk and convert it to another format (qcow2 in this case, but the format is not of importance now).
b) Get that image out from the system.
c) Attach it again on the new machine to the iSCSI NAS.

I don't know how to do this because I cannot "read" the iSCSI partition from the NAS (QNAP). From XenServer, I know how to create a snapshot to local storage, so It would not be so difficult to migrate that image. But... how to go back to iSCSI later?.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get disk image do P2V and/or V2V:

- attach iSCSI to Windows by ISCSI initialtor.
- create VHDX using Disk2vhd (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx)
- convert VHDX to QCOW using StarWind V2V then use disk image for (https://www.starwindsoftware.com/converter)

To move image to physical host do P2P and/or V2P with help of clonezilla

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-clonezilla/

Try it. Reply with results.

Comment: We using P2V VMware converter (it is very helpful in VMware infrastructure):
http://www.vmware.com/us/products/converter.html
Also, agreed with Mr. Raspberry, StrarWind V2V was very useful for us to convert our VMs.